# How To Delete A File Being Used By Another Process?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, locking

Before I begin, I should mention that this isn't really something I want to do, I'm simply curious about how it works.

I have this method called `AddLayer()`, which opens a local geodatabase file and creates a map with it:

```
public async void AddLayer()
{
    try
    {
        // open a geodatabase on the local device
        gdb = await Geodatabase.OpenAsync(@"..\..\..\test.geodatabase");

        // get the first geodatabase feature table
        var gdbFeatureTable = gdb.FeatureTables.FirstOrDefault();

        //create a layer for the feature table
        lyr = new FeatureLayer
        {
            ID = gdbFeatureTable.Name,
            DisplayName = gdbFeatureTable.Name,
            FeatureTable = gdbFeatureTable
        };

        // add the graphics to the map
        MyMapView.Map.Layers.Add(lyr);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to create offline database: " + ex.Message);
    }

    return;
}
```

I also have another method called `RemoveLayer()`, which simply un-does everything `AddLayer()` did and then calls `GC.Collect()`.

**My question is, why, even after no longer using the resources in the file and calling the garbage collector, can I not delete the file (the geodatabase file) while the program is running?**

Is this normal behavior for all programs in Windows? Is it to avoid somehow corrupting the program?

Thank you all for helping me understand this.

Comment: Don't use `async void`.

Comment: I assume `gdb` is a member variable, and you don't show where/host it is disposed.  That being the result of an open operation is probably where any open file handles would be; but without knowing much more about it or how you're disposing it, it's hard to say what specifically you could do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code below ended up working for me:

```
public void OpenGeodatabase()
{
    Geodatabase gdb = null;

    // path to .geodatabase
    var gdbPath = @"..\..\..\test.geodatabase";

    // wrap OpenAsync call in Task
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        // open a geodatabase on the local device
        gdb = await Geodatabase.OpenAsync(gdbPath);

    }).Wait();

    // get the first geodatabase feature table
    var gdbFeatureTable = gdb.FeatureTables.FirstOrDefault();

    // create a layer for the feature table
    var lyr = new FeatureLayer
    {
        ID = gdbFeatureTable.Name,
        DisplayName = gdbFeatureTable.Name,
        FeatureTable = gdbFeatureTable
    };

    // add the graphics to the map
    MyMapView.Map.Layers.Add(lyr);

    // remove the layer - to make it similar to case explanation
    MyMapView.Map.Layers.Remove(lyr);

    // make gdb reference null
    gdb = null;
    gdbFeatureTable = null;
    lyr = null;

    // call garbage collector
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    // If the works, the lock has been removed
    System.IO.File.Delete(@"..\..\..\test.geodatabase");
}
```

Basically I did everything inside of a non-async method, wrapped the call to OpenAsync within a Task, then set everything made from the geodatabase to null after use. Finally, I called the garbage collector and deleted the file.